# remove Account or invalidate auth token when logging out from app?

Tags: android, accountmanager

i am using android `AccountManager` in my app. In the splash screen i call `getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded`to get auth token or show login screen it no account is present in app.

```
private void getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded(String accountType, String authTokenType) {
    final AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthTokenByFeatures(accountType, authTokenType, null, this, null, null,
            new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                    Bundle bnd = null;
                    try {
                        bnd = future.getResult();
                        final String authtoken = bnd.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
                        LogUtils.ShowToast(SplashScreen.this, authtoken);
                        if(authtoken!=null)
                        {
                            goToHomePage();
                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }
    , null);
}
```

When the log out is pressed i call

```
AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(HomeActivity.this);
            manager.invalidateAuthToken(Constants.CONTENT_AUTHORITY,preferences.getString(Constants.AUTH_TOKEN,""));
```

to remove the authToken. and the auth token is removed.

now when i go back to the Splash Screen and `getTokenForAccountCreateIfNeeded` is called it return an empty bundle. so as the access token is null nothing happens.

should i remove the account when the user logout or should i call somthing else to show the login page when the access token is null. if i should call some othe method then pls tell which method to call to show login.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I think you missed else part of your code to navigate to Login page if access token is null.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exact behaviour do you want. What is the reason for keeping the account without auth token? Only instant re-authentication with stored credentials comes to my mind. You can implement the logic in `getAuthToken()` method of your Authenticator. Otherwise, you should remove the account so the user will know he is logged out and have to input login/pass again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually your `AccountAuthenticator` should return in `getAuthToken(...)` an Intent with the Login-Activity if it cannot get an Auth-Token. Please check your implementation (example at the end).

Removing an Account could remove any connected data. For example removing an account for contacts will remove the assigned `RawContacts`. That's why I think it's better to keep the account if the user will use the account again.

```
@Override
public Bundle getAuthToken(...) {
   // get Auth Token and return Bundle with AuthToken...
   // otherwise
   return startLoginView(...)
}  

private Bundle startLoginView(AccountAuthenticatorResponse response) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourLoginActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATOR_RESPONSE,
            response);
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT, intent);
    return bundle;
}
```